# Displaying multiple lines in a label box in C#

Tags: c#

I am attempting to retrieve the checked box indices from a CheckedListBox to a label in C#.  I was able to retrieve to a ListBox, but I would prefer the formatting freedom that labels provide.  The code I have will only display the last index and appears to overwrite the others.

Here is the code I have:

```
foreach (var itemListCheck1 in CheckedListBox1.CheckedIndices) {
    string item = itemListCheck1.ToString();
    messageLabel1.Text = item + "\n";
}
```

Obviously the "\n" isn't working to provide additional lines.  I appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the label's text on each iteration. Try this:

```
messageLabel1.Text = "";
foreach (var itemListCheck1 in CheckedListBox1.CheckedIndices) {
    string item = itemListCheck1.ToString();
    messageLabel1.Text += item + "\n";
}
```

Comment: Consider using `StringBuilder` to concatenate all of the strings, and then assigning the result to the label afterward.

Comment: Also consider using `Environment.NewLine` instead of `"\n"`.

Comment: Those are both good suggestions that make the code better in a number of ways. My intent was to focus on the core problem that prevented OP's code from working as intended.